# Any elegant way to prevent users from creating a local copy?

Tags: javascript

I am about to release a one page application (html + css + js).

The application has no external dependency, which means that users could download all the files and install them in a separate location. From past experience, this is a bad scenario for at least two reasons:

- users don't receive updates that are pushed to the main location
- they tend to tweak their local copy, and I end up having to support multiple variations of the original code

Is there an elegant way to prevent this? I was considering some forceful ways like hiding a date check in the code, but I don't want to go too far and impact the business...

Comment: Welcome to the web, I guess! You could try obfuscating/minifying the javascript to make it harder for people to hack around with, but if people want to make a copy of your app, they can if it's all local code - you've given it to them by virtue of the browser :-)

Comment: don't support copies that have been changed, and if they are only supposed to use it from the live site, only give support for the latest live version.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to calculate a hash of the some critical part of the page on the client side, have it submit that to a server that responds with some other critical part of the page that needs to be decoded and executed, and if the server thinks the hash isn't correct, it doesn't return the other part.  That seems pretty drastic, though.

Comment: If you wanted, you could check `window.location.href` and if it isn't what you want, empty the document before throwing an error to prevent the rest of execution. It is easy to remove if the person who copied it knows what to look for though.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should simply refuse to support code that end-users have tweaked. Really.

Second, if people are downloading your app to use offline, then maybe you should embrace this by adding an offline mode to your app. This would discourage people from downloading the files manually (because it still works when not connected) and they would still get updates when available.  Look in to [the various offline abilities of HTML5, including the cache manifest](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html).

Comment: This is supported in IE 10. There may also be a polyfill that emulates this with javascript for IE 9.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  You're just going to have to convince people this is a bad thing to do.
Don't provide support for externally hosted applications, but beyond that, there's not a ton you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Put the page on the server under some obscure folder path. Then add a check to see if the folder path exists in `location.href`. Chances are if the user saves your file locally, they won't replicate all the folders and will just keep the filename intact.

   e.g., `http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/stackoverflow/index.htm`

   ```
   <script>
   if(!/stackoverflow/.test(location.href))location="about:blank";
   </script>
   ```
2. Set a cookie. If the page is saved locally, the cookie won't be readable.

   `if(!/stackoverflow/.test(document.cookie))location="about:blank";`

Comment: +1 the cookie is an interesting idea. It won't work in my case because the local copies actually end up on local servers, not offline.

Answer (score 0):

In few words: **No, you can't**

But if you obfuscate and minify your code, and put some anti-copy checks through your application, this can make the work of the illegal copiers a little harder, 'cause they will have to know some JS to unlock your app. But I have to repeat: copy-proof client-based apps are (and probably will ever be) just a dream.

Comment: Any suggestions for anti-copy checks? I am trying to avoid time bombs like the one I mentioned in my question...

Answer (score 0):

I saw this, thought it was interesting:

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Check out the "Advanced" radio button ....

Comment: Could you be more specific? I know about the Closure compiler, but how is it related to my issue?

Comment: @Christophe:  It has the capability to compile code heavily into not only smaller but different code than the original source, so it might be an effective means of obfuscating your code, as well as minification.